# IndexError, Python plotting

Tags: python, excel, plot

```
import csv
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\alpha\\Desktop\\sitka')
filename = 'sitka_weather_history.csv'
with open(filename) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    header_row = next(reader)
    highs=[]
    for row in reader:
        high=int(row[1])
        highs.append(row[1])


fig= plt.figure(dpi=123, figsize=(10, 6))
plt.plot(highs)
plt.show()
```

My **error** message shows

> IndexError: list index out of range

I am unsure why I get this error and what I am doing wrong, if someone can please tell me. I would appreciate it!

**EDIT**
Below is screen-shot for the csv
[image: csv screen-shot]

Comment: post the stack trace of the error, and an example of the CSV you are reading from

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alpha\eclipse-workspace\python\test5.py", line 11, in <module>
    high=int(row[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @HarisKhaliq, he means add the stack trace and sample of the CSV in the post. it looks like nothing is loading from your csv